# Можно ли слово «шеломя» истолковать как «могила»?

Tags: значение-слов, литература, литературоведение

В «Слове о полку Игореве» (оригинальный текст) есть фраза: «О Руская земле, уже за шеломянемъ еси!» Я привыкла думать, что «шеломя» — это холм, невысокая гора. Однако в переводе М. Рыльского на украинский язык — между прочим, именно в этом переводе мы изучали «Слово» в школе — это предложение звучит так: «О Русская земля, уже ты за могилою!» («О Руська земле, уже ти за могилою!») И возникает дополнительная смысловая нагрузка, не вполне уместная в данном контексте. Неужели одно из значений вышеупомянутого слова — «могила»? Это моя безграмотность или недостатки перевода?

Answer (score 1):

Ольга, ну что вы... Всё запутали. Перевод Максма Рыльского вполне добротный, чтобы не сказать больше. Почти дословный, кстати.

Ігор на Дон війська веде,
А вже лихо його тяжкеє
Підстерігають птахи на дубах,
Вовки грозу в ярах навивають,
Орли-білозерці клекотом
Звірину скликають на кості,
Лисиці брешуть на щити багряні.
О Руська земле,
Уже ти за могилою!
http://litopys.org.ua/slovo67/sl18.htm

Просто надо украинский чуть лучше знать. **"Могила"** по-украински в одном из значений и есть **"холм"**. Причем до недавнего времени оно и было основным. 
Но в русском-то **"шелом"** (множ. собирательное - "шеломенья") - это холм и ничто больше ("шлем" - вторично). Рыльский вполне нормально переводит его "могила".

Сравните У Котляревского ("Енеїда"):

Лихий їх зна, що там робили,
Було не видно з-за могили,
В льоху ж сиділи тілько вдвох.

Тут явно не "место погребения", а холм. Хотя там же есть и "могила" в русском значении, но образно - как символ смерти.

Еще у Шевченко несколько раз (письмо к брату Никите и "Розрита могила", например) - в том же значении, "холм". Не буду приводить, дабы словом "москаль" не тревожить.

Comment: Мимоходов, мне кажется более вероятным, что у Шевченко это слово подано именно в своём «классическом» значении — как место захоронения. Это по тексту же видно.

Comment: Ольга, У Шевченко - в каком из двух случаев?  В любом случае - не думаю, a) что у него так  б) что єто значение классическое для украинского. Классическое название для места погребения  "поховання" .  По Котляревскому вопросов нет?

Comment: Я имею в виду стихотворение «Розрита могила». В своих произведениях Шевченко не единожды обыгрывал мотив места захоронения Богдана Хмельницкого как своеобразного сердца Украины, её в некотором роде святыни; это относится и к вышеупомянутому произведению. Кроме того, автор упоминает, что в этих самых могилах проводятся какие-то раскопки с целью найти нечто и/или осквернить место. Я не думаю, что в данном контексте Шевченко имеет в виду холм, образовавшийся естественным путём, а не искусственно созданную ранее насыпь или курган. «Поховання» — это погребение, т.е. сам процесс.

Comment: @Ольга *В своих произведениях Шевченко не единожды обыгрывал мотив места захоронения Богдана Хмельницкого как своеобразного сердца Украины* - ну это вы уже в плену советской идеологической системі. Ну какой там Хмельницкий? Его и рядом не лежало. "Ой Богдане, Богданочку, Якби була знала, У колисці б задушила,
Під серцем приспала." - вот это Шевченко, несколькими строками віше. И после этого "могили милi" - о нем же?! Ладно, єто к вопросу не относится, да и не об украинском мі язіке в конце концов.

Comment: *«Поховання» — это погребение, т.е. сам процесс* - тоже неверно. "" Погребение - да, но не только процесс, но и место.  ***"В Україні могилою також здавна називають високий насип на місці давнього поховання (курган)."*** https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0 Здесь в одной фразе на два ваших вопрос ответ. И поховання - место и могила - курган. Ладно, не об этом мы.

Comment: Я как-то привыкла использовать словосочетание «мiсце поховання», если речь о месте погребения. Хорошо, не суть так не суть. О «плене советской идеологической системы» — вообще не поняла, что Вы имеете в виду. Я не знаю, был ли в советские времена какой-то культ Хмельницкого, так как не застала даже развала СССР.